# Use the windows phone 8.1 camera With Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, camera, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

> I am creating an application with the ionic framework.
>
> I need to use the device's camera.
>
> I did test on Android and had no problem.
>
> But on windows phone 8.1 could not use the camera.  The code I'm using
>   is below.

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

> ### Adding dependency

```
   angular.module('starter.menu', ['starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
```

> ### `<script src="js/lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>`

```
$scope.takePicture = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            targetWidth: 600,
            targetHeight: 600,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            correctOrientation: true
        };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function (err) {

        console.log("CAMERA ERROR - " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
```

My View

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="Title">
        <ion-content style="margin : 5px !important;">
            <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
            <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" width="100%" ng-src="./img/placehold-800x500.jpg">
            <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Picture</button>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

ERROR: JavaScript runtime error: NotFoundError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

source : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.getPicture